# Django deep serialization - follow reverse foreign key constraints

Tags: django, json, django-serializer

I have two models with a foreign key relationship:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    field 1
    field 2

class Employee(models.Model):
    company = Model.ForeignKey('Company')
    field 3
    field 4
```

I would like to JSON serialize a company instance, and include all employees that have foreign-key relationships to it. IE, I'd like to create JSON that looks something like the following, in that it includes all fields for a company and all fields for all related employees.

```
[
{
    "pk": 2,
    "model": "app.company",
    "fields": {
        "field1": "value",
        "field2": "value",
        "employee": [
            {
                "pk": 19,
                "model": "app.employee",
                "fields": {
                    "field3": "value",
                    "field4": "value",
                }
            },
            {
                "pk": 25,
                "model": "app.employee",
                "fields": {
                    "field3": "value",
                    "field4": "value",
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
]
```

The Django serializer doesn't serialize relationships. Other questions here have asked how to deep serialize, but in the opposite direction -- IE, serialize an employee along with its related company. Answers to these questions have pointed out that the wadofstuff django-full-serializer plugin allows you to do this kind of deep serialization. The problem is that the wadofstuff plugin only follows these relationships unidirectionally -- it won't follow a reverse foreign key constraint. So, I'm trying to roll my own here. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

So, here's a *super* budget way of doing this which works for my purposes, but I feel like there has to be a better way (including it here in case others are looking for how to do this). It works for me only because I'm sending just one Company object at a time, and as such the fact that it doesn't explicitly preserve the relationship hierarchy isn't a big deal.

Given Company instance of "company":

```
companyJSON = serializers.serialize('json', [company, ])
employeeJSON = serializers.serialize('json', company.employee_set.all())
fullJSON = companyJSON[:-1] + ", " + employeeJSON[1:]
```